Putting up a ceiling lamp when there is a wireless actuator/receiver
I had asked a related question previously.
Basically, there is an actuator/receiver in the ceiling that is not connected to a light source. There is a wireless switch that can theoretically turn it on/off.
I want to hook up a ceiling light there now. I guess a pull chain switch would solve all my problems, but, unfortunately, it doesn't fit the design of the house.
If I remove the actuator, I don't have a switch to turn the new light on/off. Would a remote-controlled bulb help with this? If so, should I "turn on" the actuator, remove it (after shutting off the main electricity), put the new lamp and the bulb in so it's always on, but now the bulb can be switched on/off via a remote switch? Or is it already "always on"?
Or, do you think is there a way to hook up the new lamp directly to the actuator and use the existing remote switch?
This is the actuator

Could the actuator be another name for a receiver for the wireless switch?  If it connected to house/main power, then a light should be able to be connected to it.  Contacting the company should give you instructions on how to use it.

Yes, it is a receiver, I believe. Last time I contacted the company, they didn't want to give too much advice due to prevent from getting sued in case something went wrong (this is my speculation, of course).

If you pull the device out of the ceiling are there any wires behind it?  I'm pretty sure you can connect any ceiling light fixture to it, and control it with your remote control buttons. But it needs an unswitched 230V power source.   Also, if there is power available, you'll need the manual.  https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1710665/Gira-5423-00.html

Also, apparently, this whole system has a hub or server somewhere. Maybe somewhere in your house?  You very much should find out where it is, and learn how to access, program, and maintain it.

As far as I know, there is no hub/server. Maybe there was a hub/server brought for setting up the connections, but there is no hub anymore. I'll pull out the device soon to look more in detail. Even if I can connect a light fixture to it, I'm not sure where the cables should be put in in the device or whether that button with the arrow should be turned to another connection type.
